# Perl Regex: How to match exactly one of a character

Tags: regex, perl

I'm new to regular expressions in general, and in prepping for a Perl class that I am taking in the fall semester, I wanted to get my feet wet early. I'm still wrapping my head around them, and doing very basic things to get an idea of how matching and substitution works. So I wrote a simple script that checks to see if an employee's id number is valid. The simple requirements I came up with are:

1. Has to start with a 9
2. Can only have one zero in the whole number

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make the condition fail if it has more than one zero. My code looks like this:

```
$s;
print("Please enter your id number: ");
$s = <STDIN>;

if(($s =~ /^9/) && ($s =~ /0{1}/))
{
    print("ID is valid\n");
}
else
{
    print("ID not valid\n");
}
```

The second part of the condition ($s =~ /0{1}/) I am reading as, "Match only one zero" but it will not work if the number is something that contains multiple zeros as long as they aren't repeated (ex: 90401 is returned as valid, where 90091 is not valid). I know this has go to be possible, but I've tried quite a few combinations with no solution. Any point in the right direction would be most helpful.

Comment: Maybe something like =~ 0.*0 ? read as "0 any char 0" this will match if there are more than one 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most efficient code would be code that rejects bad cases that are most likely to happen (containing non-numbers) then cases that are fast for perl to check (begins with 9) and then the final case (no more than 1 zero).

```
if ($s =~ m/[^0-9]/ || $s =~ m/^[^9]/ || ($s =~ s/0/0/g) > 1) {
print "Invalid\n";
}
```

A quick single regular expression that is true if the ID is valid is this, but it's still slower than my first solution on invalid inputs, and no faster on valid inputs:

```
m/^9[1-9]*(0[1-9]*)?$/
```

This is as fast of a regular expression as I think there can be for doing the job in one operation. Using a ?: non-capturing group seems like it would go faster, and it should, but in actual implementations of perl, it goes slower by about 15%.

Comment: Do you need the number to have exactly one 0, or at most one 0? If you need exactly one 0, then change the > 1 to be == 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This regex should do that:

```
/^9[1-9]*0?[1-9]*$/
```

Start with 9, arbitrary number of 1-9, possibly a 0, followed by an arbitrary number of 1-9.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($s =~ /^9[1-9]*0?[1-9]*$/)
```

Or you could use `@{[$n =~ /0/g]}` to count "0".

```
if (($s =~ /^9[0-9]+$/) && (@{[$s =~ /0/g]} <= 1))
```

Comment: This does seem to be the most efficient answer, but you should say <= 1 instead of == 1. But you forgot to check that only numbers are included. The two requirements didn't mention only numbers, but probably only numbers are wanted.

Comment: Yes as I get more experience doing these I will add things like making sure it is all numbers and maybe limiting the amount of digits to a certain size. How do I semantically read your counting condition (the part that starts with the @)?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that for now--too advanced.  Just so you know, I would never write code like that in my programs.  I would only use code like that in an obfuscation context.  That code involves executing code inside an array reference literal [ ], which provides list context for the results of the match, giving you something like: [0, 0, 0], and then the @{} dereferences the array reference into an array, and an array in boolean  context(a scalar context) is the length of the array.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the match operator m// (or // for short) scans a string for the first match to a pattern, then it quits.

> I am reading as, "Match only one zero"

It actually reads, "Match a 0 exactly one time."

So the match operator will scan the string "900009", and find a match for 0 exactly one time at position 1 in the string, then quit.  The match operator would also find a match for 0 exactly 2 times, and a match for 0 exactly 3 times, and a match for 0 exactly 4 times at position 1 in the string as well.

> I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make the condition fail if it has more than one zero.<

How about finding all the matches for 0 in the string and if it's more than 1, then rejecting the string?

```
use strict;   
use warnings;   
use 5.012;  

my @strings = (
    "90909",
    "909",
    "999",
);

for my $str (@strings) {
    my @matches = $str =~ /0/g;
    say scalar @matches;
}

--output:--
2
1
0
```

There's actually a fancy way of getting the count in one line:

```
my $count = () = $str =~ /0/g;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about the matching, very insightful.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually lots of redundancy in the accepted answer. And not only does it count *all* zeros, it spends needless time replacing them!?

The following doesn't have as much redundancy, and it stops as soon as it finds two zeros:

```
/^9[0-9]*\z/ && /^[^0]*+(?:0[^0]*+)?+\z/
   or die;
```

Comment: Have you timed your solution? I tested yours on some random IDs versus mine (I wondered if somehow Perl's regular expressions performed differently than they have in my past 14 years of using Perl). Your code took .223 seconds to process 100,000 IDs, and my code only took 0.053. Although my code is longer, your regular expressions are actually more computationally intensive. Replacing the 0s with 0s is faster than using other variables to count them, but you are correct that I didn't need to count all of them.